# Can we have two subdomains as foo.bar.example.com and *.bar.example.com?

Tags: url, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53, nginx-ingress

> I have two subdomains in amazon route53: ***.bar.example.com** and
> **foo.bar.example.com** and in the backend the two microservices they
> were hitting was different which we defined in ingress resource rules.
> When we hit foo.bar.example.com will it redirected to foo.bar service
> or will it redirect to wildcard service and viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard is only the default value if nothing matches.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

> This wildcard DNS record will cause DNS lookups on domain names ending in example.com **that do not exist**

(emphasis mine)

PS: there is no "redirection" in the DNS; this is a term existing at the HTTP layer.